# Asp.Net WebAPI deferred select gets wrong culture

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET WebAPI controller I have the following code:

```
var cultures = [Get culture strings from DB]
var model = cultures.Select(culture => new MyModel
{
    Name = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture).NativeName,
    IsCurrent = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture).Equals(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
})
return Ok(model);
```

I also have a filter that sets the current language based on the Accept-Language  header using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;`

In my code I recently switched to attribute routing (although it might not be the cause) and now I am seeing a strange behavior: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is wrong for the select query. If I look in the debugger the correct culture is set and if I expand the IEnumerable it gets the correct culture but when I look at the result in my browser the servers culture is instead used. I think that this is because the select query is deffered and somehow the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is reset. If I do `ToList()` on the model it is correct.

Am I doing something wrong in my language filter or do I have to make sure not to return Select from controllers?